# create web api with ado that reads from the body in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api2

im developing post web api using visual studio, the api should accept a request from the body and pass to stored procedure to get array of json,

in vb was working but when i switched to c#, something wrong went on

here is my code

```
 public class BrandsController : ApiController
{



    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult getsub([FromBody] JObject data)
    {

        using (GaminBrainEntities entities = new GaminBrainEntities())
        {
            JToken a = data.SelectToken("pk");

            return Ok(entities.SP_Brands_Get_By_Category(a).ToArray);
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da00u.png)

and here is a screen shot

any help would be appreaciaated

Comment: You want the value of `a`, not `a` itself. What is the VB code that works?

Comment: Convert JToken object to long value by doing `a.ToObject<long>()`

Comment: <HttpPost>
        Public Function getsub(<FromBody> ByVal data As JObject) As IHttpActionResult
            Using entities As IAPD_DBEntities = New IAPD_DBEntities()
                Dim id As JValue = data.SelectToken("pk")
                Return Ok(entities.messages_multimedia(id).ToArray)
            End Using
        End Function

Comment: still not working